# Android: Retrofit 500 Internal server error

Tags: android, request, retrofit, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

here is my code, the request from postman is ok and everything from server side is ok, but from device I'm getting 500 code internal server error, here is my code, anyone can help me please?!.

[Postman Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bryfO.png)
[Postman Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AoLs.png)

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/v1/password/updatePassword")
    Call<ResponseUpdatePassword> updatePassword(@Header("Authorization") String BearerToken, @FieldMap Map<String, String> fieldsMap);
```

```
 public MutableLiveData<Response<ResponseUpdatePassword>> updatePassword(String token, Map<String, String> hashMap) {
        webservice.updatePassword(token, hashMap).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseUpdatePassword>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseUpdatePassword> call, Response<ResponseUpdatePassword> response) {
                responseUpdatePassword.postValue(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseUpdatePassword> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                Log.d(TAG, "updatePassword:onFailure:" + t.getLocalizedMessage());
                responseRequestFailer.postValue(true);
            }
        });
        return responseUpdatePassword;
    }
```

```
public LiveData<Response<ResponseUpdatePassword>> updatePassword(String token, String password, String password_confirmation) {
        Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("password", password);
        hashMap.put("password_confirmation", password_confirmation);
        return userRepository.updatePassword(token, hashMap);
    }
```

```
 forgetPasswordViewModel.updatePassword(token, password, password_confirmation).observe(ForgetPasswordActivity.this, this::getResponseUpdatePassword);
```

```
    private void getResponseUpdatePassword(Response<ResponseUpdatePassword> response) {
        endProgressLoadingDialog();
        if (response != null) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "" + response.body().getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Shard.lunchLoginActivity(this);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_occurred, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: how you send token using Bearer

Comment: @Amitpandey from another API in response

Comment: take a screen shot and show your post man

Comment: @Amitpandey [https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AoLs.png]

Answer (score 0):

how you send token using Bearer and also check in post man are you sending data in body or just parms or try like this one time

```
@POST("api/v1/password/updatePassword")
Call<ResponseUpdatePassword> updatePassword(@Header("Authorization") String BearerToken,
@Body UpdatePassword updatePassword);
```

make a class

```
public class UpdatePassword {  
private String password;
private String password_confirmation;

public UpdatePassword (String password, String password_confirmation) {
    this.password= password;
    this.password_confirmation= password_confirmation;
}
```

}

and send like this

```
 UpdatePassword  updatePassword=new UpdatePassword (password,confirmPassword) 
 userRepository.updatePassword(token, updatePassword)
```

Comment: [i.stack.imgur.com/2AoLs.png]  here postman screen shot, and I'm try your solution it's not working

Comment: show me your header please and also now try to send data into body

Comment: Header is empty also